# Deja de funcionar, agregar y mostrar archivos con delimitadores C++

Tags: c++

Tengo un programa en el que capturo y muestro con delimitadores, intento usar tokens con la función `strtok` para separar el registro por los mismos delimitadores pero a la hora de imprimirlos solo me imprime el primer registro del archivo y luego deja de funcionar y no tengo idea por qué, **¿alguien sabe cual es mi error?**

Según yo, el problema es con la función mostrar, pues los agrega bien en el archivo.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class User{

    public:
        void capture();
        void show();
        void deleteU();
        void searchU();
        void edit();

        char idUser[30];
        char name[30];
        char mail[40];
        char tel[20];
        char ranking[30];
        char idProfile[30];
};

int main(){
    int op;
    User x;
    int z=1;
    cout<<"|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||FILE EDITOR||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||"<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"PLEASE TYPE EVERYTHING WITH CAPITAL LETTERS, OTHERWISE YOU MAY HAVE PROBLEMS FINDING A FILE"<<endl;
    while(z!=0){
        cout<<"What do you want to do?"<<endl;
        cout<<"\t 1)Capture"<<endl;
        cout<<"\t 2)Show"<<endl;
        cout<<"\t 3)Delete"<<endl;
        cout<<"\t 4)Search"<<endl;
        cout<<"\t 5)Edit"<<endl;
        cin>>op;

            switch(op)
            {
                case 1:
                    x.capture();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    x.show();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    x.deleteU();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    x.searchU();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    x.edit();
                    break;
                default:
                    cout<<"Your option was invalid, type a valid number."<<endl;
            }
    }
    return 0;
}

void User::capture()
{
    cout<<"Give me the ID USER: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get(idUser,30);
    cout<<"Give me the NAME: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get(name,30);
    cout<<"Give me the MAIL: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get(mail,40);
    cout<<"Give me the TELEPHONE NUMBER: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get(tel,20);
    cout<<"Give me the RANKING: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get(ranking,30);
    cout<<"Give me the ID PROFILE: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get(idProfile,30);

    ofstream write("User.txt",ios::app);
    if (!write.good())
    {
        cout<<"\n\n\tFile not found."<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        write<<idUser<<'|'<<name<<'|'<<mail<<'|'<<tel<<'|'<<ranking<<'|'<<idProfile<<'|'<<'\n';
    }
    write.close();
}
void User::show()
{
    ifstream read;
    read.open("User.txt");
    char line[200];
    read.getline(line,sizeof(line));
    while(!read.eof()){
        for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
            char *pointer;
            if(i==0){
                pointer = strtok(line,"|");
                strcpy(idUser,pointer);
            }
            else if(i==1){
                pointer = strtok(NULL,"|");
                strcpy(name,pointer);
            }
            else if(i==2){
                pointer = strtok(NULL,"|");
                strcpy(mail,pointer);
            }
            else if(i==3){
                pointer = strtok(NULL,"|");
                strcpy(tel,pointer);
            }
            else if(i==4){
                pointer = strtok(NULL,"|");
                strcpy(ranking,pointer);
            }
            else if(i==5){
                pointer = strtok(NULL,"|");
                strcpy(idProfile,pointer);
            }
        }
                    cout<<"ID USER: "<<idUser<<endl;
                    cout<<"NAME: "<<name<<endl;
                    cout<<"MAIL: "<<mail<<endl;
                    cout<<"TEL: "<<tel<<endl;
                    cout<<"RANKING: "<<ranking<<endl;
                    cout<<"ID PROFILE: "<<idProfile<<endl;
                    cout<<"_________________________________"<<endl<<endl;
    }
    read.close();
}

void User::deleteU()
{
}
void User::searchU()
{
}
void User::edit()
{/*
    ofstream aux;
    ifstream lectura;
    encontrado=false;
    int auxClave=0;
    char auxNombre[30];
    aux.open("auxiliar.txt",ios::out);
    lectura.open("alumnos.txt",ios::in);
    if(aux.is_open() && lectura.is_open()){
        cout<<"Ingresa la Clave del Alumno que deseas Modificar: ";
        cin>>auxClave;
        lectura>>clave;
        while(!lectura.eof()){
            lectura>>nombre>>semestre>>grupo>>edad;
            if(auxClave==clave){
                encontrado=true;
                cout<<"__________________________"<<endl;
                cout<<"Clave: "<<clave<<endl;
                cout<<"Nombre: "<<nombre<<endl;
                cout<<"Semestre: "<<semestre<<endl;
                cout<<"Grupo: "<<grupo<<endl;
                cout<<"Edad: "<<edad<<endl;
                cout<<"__________________________"<<endl;
                cout<<"Ingresa el Nuevo Nombre del alumno con Clave "<<clave<<": ";
                cin>>auxNombre;
                aux<<clave<<" "<<auxNombre<<" "<<semestre<<" "<<grupo<<" "<<edad<<endl;
                cout<<"Registro Modificado"<<endl;
            }else{
                aux<<clave<<" "<<nombre<<" "<<semestre<<" "<<grupo<<" "<<edad<<endl;
            }
            lectura>>clave;
        }
    }else{
        cout<<"No se pudoAbrir el Archivo o aun no ha sido Creado"<<endl;
    }
    if(encontrado==false){
        cout<<"No se encontro ningun registro con clave "<<auxClave<<endl;
    }
    aux.close();
    lectura.close();
    remove("alumnos.txt");
    rename("auxiliar.txt","alumnos.txt");*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Revisa tu algoritmo... solo estás leyendo la primera línea del fichero:

```
read.getline(line,sizeof(line)); // <-- fuera del bucle
while(!read.eof()){ // <-- Aqui comienza el bucle
  // Aqui no hay mas lecturas
}
```

La solución más sencilla seguramente sea añadir una segunda lectura al final del bucle:

```
read.getline(line,sizeof(line));
while(!read.eof()){
  // ...
  read.getline(line,sizeof(line));
}
```

Por otro lado no entiendo qué sentido tiene el bucle `for` que tienes ahí montado... te puedes cargar el bucle y el código seguiría siendo funcional:

```
//    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        char *pointer;
//        if(i==0){
            pointer = strtok(line,"|");
            strcpy(idUser,pointer);
//        }
//        else if(i==1){
            pointer = strtok(NULL,"|");
            strcpy(name,pointer);
//        }
//        else if(i==2){
            pointer = strtok(NULL,"|");
            strcpy(mail,pointer);
//        }
//        else if(i==3){
            pointer = strtok(NULL,"|");
            strcpy(tel,pointer);
//        }
//        else if(i==4){
            pointer = strtok(NULL,"|");
            strcpy(ranking,pointer);
//        }
//        else if(i==5){
            pointer = strtok(NULL,"|");
            strcpy(idProfile,pointer);
//        }
```

Por cierto, si no te lo está impidiendo el ejercicio, plantéate usar `std::string` en vez de `char[]` para almacenar las cadenas de caracteres.